Minimum volume of benzene with percentage yield


The overall yield for the synthesis of N-phenylethanamide from benzene was found to be $35.2\%$.
Calculate the minimum volume of benzene, in $\mathrm{cm}^3$, required to make $10.0\, \mathrm{g}$ of N-phenylethanamide.
[Density of benzene = $0.879\, \mathrm{g\cdot cm}^{-3}$]

To work out the answer, I did the following.

Mr of N-phenyl... = $135\, \mathrm{g\cdot mol}^{-1}$
Mr of benzene = $78\, \mathrm{g\cdot mol}^{-1}$

Moles of N-phenyl... = $10/135 = 0.074074 = \mathrm{mol}$ of benzene due to 1:1 ratio
Mass of benzene = $0.074074 x 78 = 5.7778 \,\mathrm{g}$
Volume of benzene = $\frac{\mathrm{mass}}{\mathrm{density}} = \frac{5.7778}{0.879} = 6.573 \,\mathrm{cm}^3$ (This is the volume at 100% yield)
The next step is where I am unclear. I took the percentage yield equation as $(X/6.573)\times 100=35.2$
where $X$ is the volume of benzene to produce $35.2\%$ of N-phenylethanamide.
Answer = $2.31 \,\mathrm{cm}^3$.
However the mark scheme takes the volume of benzene at 100%, divides it by 35.2, then multiplies it by 100 to get $18.7 \,\mathrm{cm}^3$
What is the reason for dividing by 35.2 and multiplying by 100?

Instead think of it as multiplying by 100, then dividing by 35.2. Multiplying by 100 would give the mass of benzene required if the yield was 1% (need 100 times more benzene for a 1% yield compared to a 100% yield), dividing by 35.2 then gives you the mass required with a yield of 35.2%

It's not very clear to me why though... if volume : yield = 100% : 6.573 cm^3, then I should find for 35.2% : Volume. However, it still doesn't divide by 35.2. Also everything is in a 1:1 ratio why do I need 100 times more benene?

If all the reactions were to give 100% yield then you would need $\pu{5,7778g}$ of benzene to get $\pu{10g}$ of N-phenylacetamide, but since only $\pu{35,2g}$ out of $\pu{100g}$ of benzene actually transform into N-phenylacetamide you have
$$\frac{\pu{5,7778 g of benzene transformed into product}}{\pu{X g of benzene introduced}}=\frac{35,2}{100}$$
we get $\pu{X = 16,414 g}$ of benzene (Notice how 35,2% of 16,414 is approximately  5,7778)
Because the density of benzene is $\pu{0,879\frac{g}{cm^3}}$ => $\pu{\frac{\pu{1 cm^3}}{\pu{0,879g}}}\times\pu{16,414g benzene\simeq \pu{18,7cm^3}}$
